# How to Compare one Column of Table with other Column of other Row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

---

I would like to compare the value of one column with another column of other row. I tried to accomplish this using self join but its not working perfectly. Is there a efficient way 
to do this without using cursor. The example table are shown below. I am interested to find if FromDate2 from Table2 lies between Date Range ThruDate1 of Row1 and FromDate1 of Row2. And if it lies then update the Count in Row 1 with 2 since there two rows 1 and 2  in table 2 which lies between data range. And also if there is no 3rd row in Table1 to take range then find if FromDate2 from row3 from table2 is >= ThruDate1 of row 1 of Table 1.

Table1:

```
Row    MemberID1    FromDate1    ThruDate1        Count 
1         Mem1      01/10/2012   01/12/2012       
2         Mem1      02/01/2012   02/10/2012
```

Table 2:

```
Row       MemberID2  FromDate2    
 1        Mem1         01/14/2012     
 2        Mem1         01/17/2012     
 3        Mem1         02/11/2012
```

I really appreicate if some one could help me on this issue.

Thanks, 
Sam

Comment: What do you want to be the count when there is `row3` in table2?

Answer (score 1):

If I have undeerstand you correctly this query will do the work :

```
update Table1 SET Count = 2 
where Row = 1 AND 
EXISTS
(select * from Table2
where FromDate2 Between
(select ThruDate1 from Table1 where Row = 1)
AND
(select FromDate1 from Table1 where Row = 2));
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50453/7)

Answer (score 0):

I probably misunderstood, but that's what I think you want to achieve:

1. For every row in `Table1`, create a range from `ThruDate1` to `[next row with same MemberID1].FromDate1`.
2. Update the `Count` with the number of rows from `Table2` that have the same member id and falls between the determined range at step 1.

However, I am not sure how you want cases where there's not next row to create a range in `Table1`.

Anyway, **[here's the example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e602/2/0)**.

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 
    Row,
    (
      SELECT TOP 1 FromDate1
      FROM Table1
      WHERE Row > t1.Row AND MemberID1 = t1.MemberID1
      ORDER BY Row
    ) AS NextDate
  FROM Table1 t1
)
UPDATE t1
SET [Count] = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2
    WHERE
      MemberID2 = t1.MemberID1
      AND FromDate2 BETWEEN t1.ThruDate1 AND data.NextDate
)
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN data
  ON t1.Row = data.Row;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this works only for  the count where there is a row to create a range. But will not count for those matching rows in table2 whose FromDate2 >= ThruDate1 . Even the above exampel count for Table1 Row2 should be 1.

Comment: @KtmGuy Well I'm sorry, but I simply do not understand what should be done where there isin't a next row in Table1 to create a range using the current row and the next row values. If you could explain it in detail, perhaps in a different way I am sure that it's quite simple to modify the current example to give exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks. I think  I was able to Update [count] using  the following for the case when there is no row in table1 to create a range.  SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table2 
    WHERE
      MemberID2 = t1.MemberID1 and data.NextDate is null 
      AND FromDate2 BETWEEN t1.ThruDate1 AND '05/30/2013' For my case i have considered date 5/30/2013.

Comment: @KtmGuy It's not a fullblown solution, but since you've built your solution on it, have you considered accepting my answer?

Comment: Thank you @plalx. Yes.I have considered accepting your answer.